# Netplan: Access Point setup with WPA2 authentication

Tags: 22.04, netplan, wireless-access-point, wpa2

I can successfully set up a Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu 22.04 Server to act as an access point with netplan.

It's set up as per the details in https://netplan.io/reference#properties-for-device-type-wifis which states "Enable WPA2 authentication and set the passphrase for it."

But when I connect to it from Windows, it states that the security type is "WPA-Personal", while connecting to another router I have, I see a security type of "WPA2-Personal".  This suggests to me that the connection to the Raspberry Pi is only WPA and not WPA2.

I have tried numerous combinations of options, but with no success.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "APNAME":
          auth:
            key-management: psk
            password: "Password"
          mode: ap
          band: 5GHz
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC the NetworkManager backend uses WPA+WPA2 security by default on any hotspot/AP setup.

You should be able to view the supported security protocols, using:
`nmcli device wifi list`

NetworkManager can be forced to use WPA (`wifi-security.proto=wpa`) or WPA2 (`wifi-security.proto=rsn`) only, but Netplan cannot control this setting natively. You should be able to use a passthrough setting to control it, though:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "APNAME":
          auth:
            key-management: psk
            password: "Password"
          mode: ap
          band: 5GHz
          networkmanager:
            passthrough:
              wifi-security.proto: "rsn" # WPA2 only
              #wifi-security.group: "ccmp" # optionally choose encryption algorithm
              #wifi-security.pairwise: "ccmp" # optionally choose encryption algorithm
```

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for to force WPA2 is:

`nmcli con modify APNAME 802-11-wireless-security.proto rsn`